# Why porting Android to x86 is difficult?

Tags: android, compilation, x86

I'd like to know the technical difficulty in porting Android to x86 architecture.
Since its source is open, what is the main difficulty in getting to run on x86? 
Or is it correct to ask why it cannot be compiled to a Java bytecode to run on a JVM on a PC? Is it because of the Dalvik VM?
I'd appreciate if somebody could explain this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is already ported to x86: http://www.android-x86.org/

Also, Android does not run in a JVM. The Android Kernel is a modified Linux Kernel and written in C. You can't compile it to run in a JVM.

The DVM (used by Android) is a modified JVM based on the OpenSource JVM-implementation [Apache Harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/). All Java-Applications on Android run in a DVM.

Comment: Thank you Lukas. I did not know that it doesn't run on a JVM. I thought DVM is the JVM of Android. Thank you for the information. So what is the main thing one would have to do when getting Android to run on x86? or any other architecture than ARM? Modify the Kernel to x86 instruction set?

Comment: You can find the changes they made to make the system run here: http://git.android-x86.org/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a problem.  VirtualBox can run an android OS guest machine just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The main difficulty is that x86 and ARM are totally different architectures. They have a totally different mentality about them, different instructions, different registers, different behaviours, different memory architecture, etc. Even the way they interface with other hardware is different.

In terms of technical difficulty, the architectures don't have instructions or mechanisms that are compatible with each other, so the behaviour that is relied upon by a compiler for ARM does not exist on x86, and vice versa.

Knowing enough about one of them to implement anything major usually means you've not spent much time dealing with the other, which just adds to the difficulty.